# Multiple strongly typed models in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a 'Create New' page in MVC 4. The page will have text fields and dropdown fields. I want the items listed in the dropdown box to come from another model.

Main Model: (ignore syntax as following code is a generic example)

```
public int MainID {get; set;}
public int location {get; set;}
...
```

someDetails Model:

```
public int detailID {get; set;}
public int MainID {get; set;}
...
public int actionID {get; set;}
```

Action Model:

```
public int actionID {get; set;}
public int location {get; set;}
public string action {get; set;}
```

`SomeDetails` carries additional information about `Main` and is linked by using `mainID`. I am interested in creating a 'Add Details' pages for `someDetails`. Part of this page will include a dropdown for `Action` that is based on the `location` field in `main`.

What would be the best way to implement the dropdown box? I have a solution that involves passing possible values in the ViewBag, but I've seen this labeled bad practice. I was also thinking that it might be possible to change `public int actionID {get; set;}` to a type of `<List>Action`. If doing this method, I think I would have the constructor for `someDetails` populate the list? Would this cause performance issues when simply viewing a particular `someDetails` since it would try to create the list each time?

Create action:

```
 public ActionResult Create(int id = -1)
    {
        if (id == -1)
        {
            //NOTE: INSERT REDIRECT HERE
        }
        someDetails model = new someDetails();
        model.MainID = id;
        return View(model);
    }
```

EDIT: 
As requested, better explanation of business logic
The `main model` I have shown is modeled after an existing table that I am not able to change as it is part of a data warehouse that lives outside my control/group. I am creating an application which allows users to add `someDetails` in order to gain better visibility/tracking of some of this data. The `Action` model simply displays possible actions/actionIDs based on the location.

My application will allow a user to search for or filter a set of items from the `main` model. They will be then allowed to add `someDetails` which will bring up a form which will contain some text fields and a dropdown list to pick an action. To get possible values for `action`, I would do something like `SELECT * FROM Action a WHERE a.location = currentLocation`

Comment: Sorry on a phone. Have you thought about usi g viewmodels?

Comment: create a composite viewmodel

Comment: ...then you cam use a SelectList declared in the viewmodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a ViewModel with properties for each model... and that ViewModel can be populated in your controller and then passed to the view.

**EDIT: For DropDownLists:**

In your ViewModel you need a property for the selected action id, and another to the list itself.

**In the model:**

```
public int actionId { get; set;}
public SelectList ListOfActions { get; set;}
//Other model members
```

**In the View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.actionId, Model.ListOfActions, "Select one action", new { @class = "yourclass" })
```

**In your controller:**

```
var model = new YourViewModel();
model.ListOfActions = new SelectList(this.GetListOfActions(), "ActionName", "ActionId", [here the selected action id in case you need it])
```

Comment: Brilliant. I totally forgot about this aspect of MVC. My brain must have gone into hibernation over the weekend. Damn Mondays. Thanks

Comment: That happends, frequently :)

Comment: I guess a followup question I have would be: What should the data type for my list be? I would need to retain the value of `actionID` and `action`. Would a dictionary fit this best?

Comment: @Jeff, I don't fully understand what are you trying to accomplish. If you could update your question with some real models (not dummy ones) and explain a bit better the business logic... we can advice you in proper way to map that into viewmodels.

Comment: I have added more details for the business logic, but I am not able to paste the entire table as the data is proprietary and contains way too many columns.

Comment: Yes it does. So when I want to save to `someDetails` table, I need to take `YourViewModel` and copy the values to a new `someDetails`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, the ViewModel just carries the information TO the view... and then the POSTED values to the action. Once in the Action method, you strip it as you wish and save it to DB.